# can I use causalimpact (BSTS) to forecast without an intervention?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, intervention-analysis, causalimpact

As a data scientist without much formal training, I'm looking to get some professional feedback on the following question:

Is it ever advisable to use causalimpact (or I guess BSTS generally) to forecast time series *without* an intervention?

I do know that causalimpact is meant to be used with an intervention, but one can't help but wonder.

I know that model choice depends on the particular data an use case, so probably the most actionable responses would be variations on:

- "never do that-- using causal impact for forecasting without an intervention is like trying to pound nails with a screwdriver because ..."
- "yes, using causalimpact without an intervention  will outperform alternative modeling approaches, but only if the following are true.."

Thanks as always for any advice!